# How can a file lock be checked in Python on Linux?

Tags: python, json, file, locking

I want to have a module that features functions to lock a file, to unlock a file, to check if a file is locked and, also, to have some functions to save and read JSON files using this locking functionality.

What would be a workable way to check if a file is locked in a general module function? I have in mind something like `locking_module.read_lock_status("file.csv")`. Below is my attempted module code and two scripts that can be run at the same time, with one writing to a file and the other reading from that same file.

## module

```
import fcntl
import json
import time
import struct
import re

def lock(filepath):
    lock_file = open(filepath, "a")
    try:
        fcntl.lockf(lock_file, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
    except (OSError, BlockingIOError) as error:
        return error
    return lock_file

def unlock(filepath):
    lock_file = open(filepath, "a")
    try:
        fcntl.lockf(lock_file, fcntl.LOCK_UN)
    except (OSError, BlockingIOError) as error:
        return error
    return lock_file

def read_lock(filepath):
    lock_file = open(filepath, "r")
    lock_data = struct.pack("hhllhh", fcntl.F_WRLCK, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    try:
        lock_query = fcntl.fcntl(lock_file, fcntl.F_GETLK, lock_data)
        lock_status = struct.unpack("hhllhh", lock_query)[0]
    except OSError:
        return False
    return lock_status

def save_JSON(filepath, dictionary, hang_until_unlocked = True):
    if lock(filepath):
        with open(filepath, "w") as file_JSON:
            json.dump(dictionary, file_JSON)
        unlock(filepath)
        return True
    elif hang_until_unlocked:
        while not lock(filepath):
            time.sleep(0.1)
        with open(filepath, "w") as file_JSON:
            json.dump(dictionary, file_JSON)
        unlock(filepath)
        return True
    else:
        return False

def load_JSON(filepath, hang_until_unlocked = True):
    if lock(filepath):
        try:
            with open(filepath) as file_JSON:
                dictionary = json.load(file_JSON)
            unlock(filepath)
            return dictionary
        except:
            return False
    elif hang_until_unlocked:
        while not lock(filepath):
            time.sleep(0.1)
        try:
            with open(filepath) as file_JSON:
                dictionary = json.load(file_JSON)
            unlock(filepath)
            return dictionary
        except:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

## script 1

```
import random

import lock

while True:
    config = {"a": 1, "b": random.randint(1, 2)}
    lock.save_JSON("config.json", config)
```

## script 2

```
import lock

while True:
    config = lock.load_JSON("config.json")
    if config:
        print(config)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use subprocess to invoke lsof from the command line like this

```
import subprocess
file_lock = str(subprocess.check_output("lsof | grep file_name", shell=True))
```